# Insert a piece of code in the text of a Label that involves variables inside kv lang

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to **insert a piece of code in the text of a Label that involves variables inside kv lang** as shown below:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size=(200,200)

Builder.load_string("""
<Screen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.width,root.height
        Label:
            id:label
            text:'Nothing'
        Button:
            id:button
            text:'Insert'
            on_release: root.insert_text()
""")

class Screen(Widget):
    def insert_text(self):
        self.ids.label.text='Something' if button.text=='Insert' else 'Nothing' #Label should say "Something" if Button's text says 'Insert'
class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    App().run()
```

**When running this code I get the error:** `NameError: name 'button' is not defined`

How can I avoid this error and have the entered code work within kv lang?
I **already tried** putting `self.ids.button.text` instead of `button.text` and despite not getting the error, **it doesn't work** inside the application either.

Edit: Also tried insert `button.text` as a **raw string** but **kv lang just ignored it**.

Comment: In `kvlang` try replacing `on_release: root.insert_text()` with `on_release: root.insert_text(self)` and in method `insert_text`, replace `insert_text(self)` with `insert_text(self, button)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Label text to change without a Button press, then you probably want to use a Property. You can reference a Property in `kv` and any changes to that Property will trigger evaluation where that Property is used. So, here is a modified version of your code that uses a Property named `follow_changes` that controls whether the Label text follows the Button text:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (200, 200)

Builder.load_string("""
<Screen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.width,root.height
        Label:
            id:label
            text: 'Something' if root.follow_changes and button.text == 'Insert' else 'Nothing'  # use follow_changes Property
        Button:
            id:button
            text:'Insert'
            on_release:
                root.follow_changes = True  # turn on following_changes
        Button:
            text: "Change Button Text"
            on_release:
                button.text = 'Abba'
""")

class Screen(Widget):
    follow_changes = BooleanProperty(False)  # Property to control Label text

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    App().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the error is `name 'button' is not defined`, you just need to define `button`. Like this:

```
def insert_text(self):
    button = self.ids.button  # define button
    self.ids.label.text='Something' if button.text=='Insert' else 'Nothing' #Label should say "Something" if Button's text says 'Insert'
```

Comment: It works if the Button from the beginning meets the condition that is requested and only takes effect in the Label when it is requested, let me explain:
If the Button is like this:

`Button:`
     `id:button`
     `text:'X'`
     `on_press: root.insert_text()`

and the function is as follows:

`button = self.ids.button`
`self.ids.label.text='Something' if button.text=='Insert' else 'Nothing'`
`self.ids.button.text='Insert'`

**(Please read the following comment)**

Comment: Although the **Label is indicated to change to say "Something" when the Button text is "Insert"**, since originally it was not, even if it changes later, it will not be taken into account, so the **Label will continue to have as text "Nothing" unless the button is pressed again** once changed.

So **its "passive" effect inside the code is unfortunately not functional**, which is what I mainly need.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you want the `Label` to change without pressing the `Button`, then perhaps you should not be using a `Button`. Exactly how do you want the `App` to perform? And is that `Button` a necessary part?

Comment: What I am looking for is that once the button is pressed, the Label is able to detect the button text in real time as indicated by the code inserted when the button is pressed. Let's say there is a second button that changes the text of the first button to say something else so the following chain of events should happen: `The "Insert" button is pressed > The Label text changes from "Nothing" to "Something" since I detect that the first button has the text "Insert" > The second button is pressed > The first button changes its text to "x" > The text displayed by the Label changes to "Nothing".`